# Nested relations in Drupal

Tags: drupal, nested

I have a D7 website where users can make content (obviously...). So every node has it's own author. Every author is a member of an organization. But he can be a member of more then one organization. So far the facts.

I would like to create a view where the content is filtered on Author. Very easy, set the relation of the view on "Content's Author" and select the *current user* as filter.
But what I would like is to filter on the author's organization. So in fact it's a nested relation. Filter the nodes on the current logged in user (that's easy), but how can I filter on the current logged in user's organization?

Comment: I think  you might need to use panels instead of just views here

Comment: a panel can display results based on another panel I not 100% sure but I think that is wht u are looking here

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look at the panel-module! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the panels didn't work out, so I wrote my own hook :-)

```
function mymodule_views_pre_view (&$view, &$display_id, &$args) {
    // Only execute this script when the view 'fiches_my_thema' is called
    if ('fiches_my_thema' == $view->name) {
        // Get users thema
        global $user;
        $userRoles = $user->roles;
        $user_themas = array();

        // Filter roles so you end up with the "Thema's".
        foreach ($userRoles as $key) {
            if(strpos($key,'edacteur')) {
                $key = str_replace('Redacteur - ','', $key);
                $key = str_replace('Eindredacteur - ','', $key);
                $user_themas[] = $key;
            }   
        }

        // Resolve tid
        $terms = taxonomy_get_tree(5);
        $allRoles = array();
        $arguments = array();

        // Assign the 'tid' to a variable
        foreach ($terms as $key) {
            $singleRoles =  $key->name;
            $allRoles[] = $singleRoles;
            if(in_array($singleRoles, $user_themas)) {
                $arguments[] = $key->tid;
            }   
        }

        // Only when the arguments are NOT empty, set the arguments
        if(!empty($arguments)) {
            $finalArguments = implode("+", $arguments);
            $args[] = "$finalArguments";
            $view->set_arguments($args);
        }
    }
}
```